# reading from a file and copying it to array: Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to copy 65,536 lines from a file to an int array of the same size using a function.
each line contains four hexadecimal digits.

I also added _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in properies => c/c++ => preprocessor definitions because i kept getting warnings because i was using f_gets and not f_gets_s to read from the file.

the error I keep getting now is:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was
>   corrupted.

when trying to print the array I see that all the lines are copied but the last line is copied twice or maybe copied once but is printed twice.
 
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES_MEMO 65536
#define NUMBER_OF_REGISTERS 16
#define CHARS_IN_LINE 5  
#define CHARS_IN_IMMEDIATE 5 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

void createFromFile(FILE *fPtrReadMemin, int *meminLines){
  //create a new array of int numbers named meminLines, with the lines of memin text file
  //gets pointers for the file memin and for the array meminLines
    FILE *copyCreateFromFile = fPtrReadMemin;
    int i = 0;
    char temp[CHARS_IN_LINE]; //used for copying to the memory array
    int temp2;

    while (!feof(copyCreateFromFile))
    {
      fgets(temp, NUMBER_OF_LINES_MEMO, copyCreateFromFile);
      if (strcmp(temp, "")==0)
      {
            break;
      }
      temp2 = (int)strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
      meminLines[i] = temp2;
      printf("%04x\n", temp2);
      i++;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    FILE*fPtrReadMemin;
    fPtrReadMemin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //open Memin to read
    int meminLines[NUMBER_OF_LINES_MEMO]; // the memory  
    if (fPtrReadMemin == NULL) { //check if the files were open correctly
        printf("There was error using files\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    createFromFile(fPtrReadMemin, meminLines); //create the memory
    system("pause");
    fclose(fPtrReadMemin);//close all files
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve], this code is incomplete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer has a length of `CHARS_IN_LINE`:

```
char temp[CHARS_IN_LINE]; //used for copying to the memory array
```

But upon calling `fgets` you provide a buffer length of `NUMBER_OF_LINES_MEMO`:

```
  fgets(temp, NUMBER_OF_LINES_MEMO, copyCreateFromFile);
```

You should provide the *actual* length of the `temp` buffer to `fgets`.

```
  fgets(temp, CHARS_IN_LINE, copyCreateFromFile);
```

or even better

```
  fgets(temp, sizeof temp, copyCreateFromFile);
```

---

Furthermore the length of the lines in your file is not 4 but 5, because `fgets` appends a `\n` at the end of the line. Therefore `CHARS_IN_LINE` should be at least 5.

---

**Not directly related:**

You can drop this line:

```
FILE *copyCreateFromFile = fPtrReadMemin;
```

and use directly `fPtrReadMemin` instead of `copyCreateFromFile`.

---

Your test of end of file is not correct, you should rather test if `fgets` returns `NULL`.

The `strcmp` is useless, you can drop it.

**Overall corrected and simplified function:**

```
void createFromFile(FILE *fPtrReadMemin, int *meminLines) {
  //create a new array of int numbers named meminLines, with the lines of memin text file
  //gets pointers for the file memin and for the array meminLines
  int i = 0;
  char temp[100]; // not using CHARS_IN_LINE but 100 which is a reasonable
                  // maximal file length.

  while (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, fPtrReadMemin) != NULL)
  {  
    meminLines[i] = (int)strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
    printf("%04x\n", meminLines[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

---

**And you forgot to include following:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: I tried using the code suggested but now i am getting another error:    
    "Exception thrown: write access violation.
    meminLines was 0x1D20112."

Comment: @NadavB That probably means that there are other bugs elsewhere in the code you didn't show. You need to provide a __[MCVE]__

Comment: i added the minimal main to my question. the debugger points out to a problem in the line "meminLines[i] = (int)strtol(temp, NULL, 16)" in the function. I think that the error pops up also at the end of printing of the array.

Comment: @NadavB you didn't apply what I suggested in line 4 of my my answer. You need `fgets(temp, CHARS_IN_LINE, copyCreateFromFile);`

Comment: @NadavB forget my previous comment. I modified the answer according to your edit. Use the __Overall corrected and simplified function__ in my answer and it will work.